# Are there any reasons why specifying the argument type is required in Java 8 lambda syntax?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have read http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-4.html and noticed that all the examples have argument type declared explicitly, even though it's already known from the interface-function declaration.

```
public interface FileFilter {
    /** ... **/
    boolean accept(File pathname);
}


FileFilter java = (File f) -> f.getName().endsWith(".java");
```

Can't we go with just

```
(f) -> f.getName().endsWith(".java"); ?
```

**UPDATE**: In the [JSR-335 Draft](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/edr/jsr335/index.html), I have found that inferred-type parameters are most likely to be supported

```
(int x) -> x+1 // Single declared-type parameter
(int x) -> { return x+1; } // Single declared-type parameter
(x) -> x+1 // Single inferred-type parameter
x -> x+1 // Parens optional for single inferred-type case
```

Comment: The reason that most of the examples used manifest parameter types, even though type inference was considered from day 1, is purely pedagogical.  The audience was assumed to be ordinary Java developers who have not seen any of this material before; throwing lambdas *and* type inference at them in one go would have been a lot to take in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an example where the type is omitted in the "4. Target typing" section

```
Comparator<String> c = (s1, s2) -> s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it depends on how late it knows the type.

In Java 7, the code on the right hand side of the `=` has no idea how the expression is to be used.  Just to get this to compile requires a design change for the compiler.

In theory you don't even need the variable declaration because its specified in the parent or could be implied.

```
FileFilter java = (File f) -> f.getName().endsWith(".java");
```

could be

```
FileFilter java = -> pathname.getName().endsWith(".java");
```

or with an implied getter.

```
FileFilter java = -> pathname.name.endsWith(".java");
```

or you could assume the parameters are imported into the name space implicitly as there is only one parameter. (Like SQL does with column names)

```
FileFilter java = -> name.endsWith(".java");
```